# Asp.Net WebApi Ошибка при скачивании больших файлов

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis

Есть следующий метод

```
[Route("{id:int}/attachment"), HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAttachment([FromUri]int id)
{
    var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var fileName = "Имя файла";
    var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
    try
    {
        var path = "Путь к файлу";
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            { FileName = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fileName) };
        result.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", mimeType);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
    }
}
```

скачивание файла инициируется отправкой ajax запроса на соответствующий endpoint webapi, спустя некоторое время после отправки запроса в консоли разработчика запрос приобретает статус **(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**, в системном журнале операционной системы нашел следующую ошибку

> ArithmeticException
> Переполнение или потеря точности в арифметической операции.
> http://localhost:58863/api/operations/22461/items/226512/attachment

как выяснилось проблема повторяется только для **больших** файлов, в данном случае размер файла составляет 1.4ГБ.

Подскажите как реализовать скачивание больших файлов

Comment: Так не надо его как byte[] передавать, открывайте `Stream` через `File.OpenRead` и отдавайте. Зачем все эти гигабайты в память целиком грузить?

Comment: не понял что Вы подразумеваете, не могли бы Вы привести пример кода, или ткнуть в документацию с примером

Comment: ASP.NET это или ASP.NET Core?

Comment: речь о asp.net, проверил, все действительно работает, хотя я вроде проверял такой вариант, может по запаре что то сделал не так и поэтому не работало, спасибо Вам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передавайте как поток данных, а не как массив байт.

```
result.Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(path));
```

Кстати, MIME Type можно задать так

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);
```